# Redirect to specific screen after receiving push notification - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, storyboard

I am receiving a push notifications and on the payload I check if the application is on the background. If yes I want to redirect the user into the Message screen for example. My app has Navigation Controllers as well as a Sliding Menu. I trying using this code :

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
            if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background  ) {
                     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Message")
                     window?.rootViewController = vc
            }
    }
```

However this screen loads when it crashes as it there are many components missing (UINavigation bars etc). Is there another way to redirect,maybe while creating the necessary segues ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing navigation bars/navigation items have you tried pushing the view controller onto a navigation stack before setting it as the root vc? For example :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Message")
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
window?.rootViewController = navVC
```